# jQuery take class from select option

Tags: jquery, forms, class, select

is it possible to take name of class from selected option in html select? 
here is code:

```
<select id="typ" name="typ">
    <option value="not">--- Zvoľte prosím typ zmluvy ---</option>
    <option value="12" class="DSL" >DSL</option>
    <option value="13" class="H" >H (Hlasové služby)</option>
</select>
```

If user select H (Hlasové služby) I want to write in span class typ class of this option in this case it's H .

Answer (score 4):

The solution with jquery is pretty simple:

```
var SelectedOptionClass = $("#typ option:selected").attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it

```
$("#typ").bind("change",function()
                   {
                       alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr("class"));
                   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MzcjB/11/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to add the class to a `<span>` that has the class `typ` already.

```
$('#typ').change( function() {
    $('span.typ').attr('class', 'tip').addClass('typ').addClass( $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class') );
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ELgSj/

**Update:**

I've added `attr('class', 'typ')`. So when you re-change the `select`-tag, all classes except the class `typ`get removed from the `<span>` and only the selected one is added.